# How to quit an online match?

Tags: rocket-arena

I'm trying to run for the Platinum trophy before the server closure, so I'll soon start to get game modes I don't need anymore, and I don't want to waste my time.

Is there a way to leave an online match without closing the game? I really can't find any option in-game that let me quit an already started match.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not harming anyone, the game is pretty much dead so every match is just me vs a bunch of IA characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an actual answer, but I found a solution:
Leaving the character idle for 30ish seconds will result in the player being kicked out of the match, with no downsides nor warnings.